# How to fix Mongo CXX missing headers in a C++ application ? (CMake)

Tags: c++, mongodb, cmake

I have installed Mongo C and Mongo CXX to build an application that uses Mongo as a database. I compile the application using CMake.

My **CMakeLists.txt** file looks like this:

```
# CMake
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.10.2)

PROJECT(Proto-buffer CXX)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# Libraries
FIND_PACKAGE(libmongocxx REQUIRED)

FIND_PACKAGE(libbsoncxx REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIR})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIR})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/local/include/mongocxx/v_noabi")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0")

# Executables
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} ./source/classes/connection/connection.cpp)
```

And the application looks like this:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

#include <iostream>

#include <vector>

#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/stdx.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>

int main(const int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    mongocxx::instance instance{};

    mongocxx::client client{mongocxx::uri{"mongodb://localhost:27017"}};

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the application `cmake ../.` inside the **build** folder, I receive the error:

```
CMakeFiles/Proto-buffer.dir/source/classes/connection/connection.cpp.o: In function `main':
connection.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::uri::uri(bsoncxx::v_noabi::string::view_or_value)'
connection.cpp:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::client::client(mongocxx::v_noabi::uri const&, mongocxx::
v_noabi::options::client const&)'
connection.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::client::~client()'
connection.cpp:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::uri::~uri()'
connection.cpp:(.text+0x129): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::uri::~uri()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/Proto-buffer.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'Proto-buffer' failed
make[2]: *** [Proto-buffer] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Proto-buffer.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Proto-buffer.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I expect to compile this application without errors. I have read the installation [documentation](http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/), [CMakeLists](https://github.com/dhandeo/cmake-mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) examples for Mongo and other questions on Stack Over Flow.

Which headers do I need to add to the CPP file, or which libraries / flags do I need to add to the **CMakeLists.txt** file to compile without errors ?

Comment: [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/target_link_libraries.html) is missing. You should also switch over and use [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) as it's better practice in general.

Comment: Also, explicitly adding include directories and library directories for the C and C++ drivers is not how you are supposed to do this. Use `find_package` - both drivers expose support for it. Please see the examples directory: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/examples/projects/mongocxx/cmake/shared/CMakeLists.txt#L39